# What is the .NET folder search hierarchy?

Tags: .net, windows

When .NET needs to load an assembly, what is the folder hierarchy that it uses to search for the assembly?  I assume it starts with the GAC, and then local folder of the executing assembly?  What is the complete hierarchy?  I know the Windows search path (for unmanaged code) is something like local folder/System32 folder/search path/etc. and I am looking for something similar for .NET.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you were looking for a description of the process rather than links to lengthy MSDN articles, this is a **brief summary of the steps**. You can find more details [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yx7xezcf%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

Steps the runtime follows to resolve an assembly reference:

1. Determines the correct assembly version by examining applicable **configuration files.**
2. Checks whether the assembly name has been bound to before and, if so, uses the **previously loaded assembly**.
3. Checks the **GAC**.
4. Probes for the assembly by following these steps:

   a) If configuration and publisher policy do not affect the original reference and if the bind request was created using the Assembly.LoadFrom method, the runtime checks for **location hints**.

   b) If a **codebase** is found in the configuration files, the runtime checks only this location.

   c) Probes for the assembly using the heuristics described in the **probing section**. If the assembly is not found after probing, the runtime requests the Windows Installer to provide the assembly. This acts as an **install-on-demand** feature.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few articles from MSDN:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yx7xezcf(v=VS.100).aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/15hyw9x3.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Look at this article [How the runtime locates assemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff527268.aspx).

It's actually not a linear path, and it depends on a lot (is the assembly loaded already, configuration files, ...) but the article is very clear.